# Construction of functions in $L^{1}$ with certain properties

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to find two functions with the following properties:

1. I'm trying to find a function $f \in L^{1}([0, \infty))$ such that $f$ is **continuous** and **not bounded**. I know that if such an $f$ exists, then it must be essentially bounded, but of course this doesn't say anything about whether $f$ exists or not.
2. On the other hand, I'm trying to find a function $h \in L^{1}([0,1])$ such that $h$ is **not bounded in any neighbourhood of $x \in [0,1]$, for every x**.

If such functions exist, I would like to compute the value of the corresponding integrals. I suspect that both functions exist, and are constructed as a limit of a certain sequence of functions, but I can't come up with examples. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Also why should a function as in 1. be essentially bounded?

Comment: For 1. think of a function with a lot of 'bumps' that get taller as $x\to \infty$ but also thinner so that the integral exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, for (1), let $f(x)$ have taller and taller spikes that get thinner and thinner as $x \to \infty$. Explicitly, for $n \ge 2$, suppose that $$f_n(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}n^4(x-n), & n \le x < n + \tfrac 1 {n^3}, \\ n^4(n+\tfrac 2 {n^3} - x), & n + \tfrac 1 {n^3} \le x < n + \frac  2 {n^3}, \\ 0, & \text{ otherwise}. \end{matrix} \right. $$ Then $f_n$ is zero except on the interval $[n,n+2/n^3]$, where the graph of $f_n$ is a triangle of height $n$ and base $2/n^3$ and thus $\int_{0}^\infty f_n(x) dx = \frac 1 {n^2}$. Now let $f = \sum_{n=2}^\infty f_n$. Then $f$ is continuous and unbounded but $\int^\infty_{0} f(x) dx = \sum^\infty_{n=2} \frac 1 {n^2} < \infty$.

For (2), you should try to exploit the facts that the rationals are dense and yet still have measure zero. Take $$h(x) = \left \{\begin{matrix} q, & \text{ if } x \in \mathbb Q \text{ and } x = \tfrac p q \text{ where } \text{gcd}(p,q)=1, \\ 0, & \text{ if } x \not \in \mathbb Q. \end{matrix} \right.$$ The function integrates to zero (in the Lebesgue sense) since it equals $0$ almost everywhere. However, it is arbitrarily large in any neighborhood since near any irrational number $y$, you can find a rational $x$ which is arbitrarily close to $y$ and has an arbitrarily large denominator when reduced.

EDIT: as an aside, this second example is closely related to [Thomae's Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function). There the goal is to make a function which is continuous only at the irrationals, and you do so in the same way, but by using $1/q$ rather than $q$.

Comment: I see, but how do you check that $f = \sum f_{n}$ is continuous? I can't use the weierstrass test here

Comment: Don’t need anything fancy here. You could easily do it from the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, by considering the cases that $x \in [n, n+ 2/n^3]$ for some $n$ (in which case $\delta = \epsilon/n^4$ works) or the case when $x$ isn’t in one of those sets (in which case you can take $\delta$ enough that $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$ doesn’t intersect on of those sets). I didn’t need to phrase the answer as an infinite sum, it was just convenient to do so, but notice that the supports of $f_n$ are disjoint.

Comment: Great, many thanks!